# "Bitwise AND" in Lua

Tags: lua, bit-manipulation, operators

I'm trying to translate a code from C to Lua and I'm facing a problem.
How can I translate a Bitwise AND in Lua?
The source C code contains:

```c
if ((command&0x80)==0)
   ...
```

How can this be done in Lua?

I am using Lua 5.1.4-8

Comment: Have you tried searching on the internet for `lua bitwise and` or `lua bitwise operations`? Because they should find you the answer you need.

Comment: Yes, I seached half hour. I see that a library for bitwise was added in 5.2, but my Router where I'm going to run this code, still run 5.1.4 and it sais that it is up-to-date.

Comment: The *very first link* on my Google (and bing and yahoo) search results is to http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators which has the information you need.

Comment: Exactly that same link I already found. But there it says "As of version 5.2, Lua ships with the library [...] Previous versions of Lua did not include bitwise operators."

Comment: Did you keep reading? Because it has more than that sentence on the page. Specifically, the **next sentence** and the **entire rest of the page** are about bitwise opreations libraries for older versions of lua.

Comment: I don't want to import anything... Btw, I have refreshed the site, and someone did responded to this question, with a aparently good solution. Now I come back, the browser refreshes and the answer is gone.... Really?!?

Comment: So find a pure-lua one and pull the code out manually. But `require`ing an appropriate module is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a basic, isolated bitwise-and implementation in pure Lua 5.1:

```
function bitand(a, b)
    local result = 0
    local bitval = 1
    while a > 0 and b > 0 do
      if a % 2 == 1 and b % 2 == 1 then -- test the rightmost bits
          result = result + bitval      -- set the current bit
      end
      bitval = bitval * 2 -- shift left
      a = math.floor(a/2) -- shift right
      b = math.floor(b/2)
    end
    return result
end
```

usage:

```
print(bitand(tonumber("1101", 2), tonumber("1001", 2))) -- prints 9 (1001)
```

Comment: These two operands are necessary to control a LCD screen. Now I am half way due to your help :)

Comment: like in the code comments, to shift left once is to multiply by 2. to shift n times: `shifted = a * 2^n`

Comment: I'm confused. You mean that I can delete all parts that contains "b" that the code will work shifting left?

Comment: no. your C code  `command = command << 1` is the same as `command = command * 2` in Lua.

Comment: Yes, almost. You do `command = math.floor(command / 2)` so that you won't get decimals. For example, 3 >> 1 should be 1 and not 1.5 so the floor function removes the decimal portion.

Comment: Oh cool. Understood now. Thanks so much for your time. And sorry for deleting my comments, I am trying not to make a mess...trying...

For other users: Between "no. your c....:" and "Yes, almost" I have questioned that `command = comment /2` is probably shift right.

Answer (score 13):

Implementation of bitwise operations in Lua 5.1 for non-negative 32-bit integers

```
OR, XOR, AND = 1, 3, 4

function bitoper(a, b, oper)
   local r, m, s = 0, 2^31
   repeat
      s,a,b = a+b+m, a%m, b%m
      r,m = r + m*oper%(s-a-b), m/2
   until m < 1
   return r
end

print(bitoper(6,3,OR))   --> 7
print(bitoper(6,3,XOR))  --> 5
print(bitoper(6,3,AND))  --> 2
```

P.S.
Lua 5.1 also has non-standard (external) library written in C: `require"bit"; x=bit.band(y,z)`
Lua 5.2 has standard `bit32` library for bitwise functions: `x=bit32.band(y,z)`
Lua 5.3+ has int64 datatype with native bitwise operators: `x=y&z`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is specifically for Lua 5.1.X

you can use

```
if( (bit.band(command,0x80)) == 0) then
...
```

in Lua 5.3.X and onwards it's very straight forward...

```
print(5 & 6)
```

hope that helped

Comment: Lua 5.1.X doesn't have this capability unless you are using LuaJIT.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how i bitwise-and a value with a constant `0x8000`:

```lua
result = (value % 65536) - (value % 32768)  -- bitwise and 0x8000
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use **Adobe Lightroom Lua**, Lightroom SDK contains `LrMath.bitAnd()` method for "bitwise AND" operation:

```lua
-- x = a AND b

local a = 11
local b = 6
local x  = import 'LrMath'.bitAnd(a, b)

-- x is 2
```

And there are also `LrMath.bitOr(a, b)` and `LrMath.bitXor(a, b)` methods for "bitwise OR" and "biwise XOR" operations.